# Word template with Latex

Tags: titlesec, templates

I am struggling to reproduce a Word template in Latex.[image: This is the word template I asked to reproduce]

I managed to reproduce the font (Calibri) switching to LualaTex with

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
```

I setup the margins using

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, 
left=25mm, right=25mm,top=25mm, bottom=25mm}
```

I also modified color

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\color{cyan}}
\sectionfont{\color{lightgray}}
```

What I can't do is to have the vertical line at the left margin. Any ideas? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `eso-pic` package. It allows you to put arbitrary content to a specific location on the page. See the following example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\author{John Doe}
\title{Some Thesis}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(200,400){\color{cyan}\rule{0.5em}{4cm}}}
\maketitle

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you! that's exactly what I was looking for.